# How to draw a planar graphic, Canonical Ordering algorithm?

Tags: graphics

For my research concerning Canonical Ordering algorithm, I need to draw this planar graph, in the following figure :
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: a start for you `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt}]
\path[nodes={text=teal}] 
(0,0)   node[c] (v1) {} node[below left]{$v_1$}
(5,0)   node[c] (v2) {} node[below right]{$v_2$}
(2.5,1) node[c] (v3) {} node[below]{$v_3$}
(2,4)   node[c] (v16){} node[above]{$v_{16}$}
;
\draw (v1)--(v2)--(v3)--(v1);
\draw 
(v1) to[bend left=30] (v16)
(v2) to[bend right] (v16)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
`

Comment: Thank you so much @BlackMild

Answer (score 2):

If someone wants here below my final result :),

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} % >>> for dummy texts only 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt},scale=.8]     
\path[nodes={text=teal}]  
(0,0)       node[c] (v1)  {} node[below left]   {$v_1$} 
(15,0)      node[c] (v2)  {} node[below right]  {$v_2$} 
(7.5,1.5)   node[c] (v3)  {} node[below]        {$v_3$} 
(9.5,2)     node[c] (v4)  {} node[below]        {$v_4$} 
(11.2,2.8)  node[c] (v5)  {} node[below]        {$v_5$} 
(13,3.5)    node[c] (v6)  {} node[right]        {$v_6$} 
(5.7,2)     node[c] (v7)  {} node[below]        {$v_7$} 
(4.1,2.5)   node[c] (v8)  {} node[below]        {$v_8$} 
(2.8,3.5)   node[c] (v9)  {} node[left]         {$v_9$} 
(5.8,4)     node[c] (v10) {} node[right]        {$v_{10}$}
(10.7,5)    node[c] (v11) {} node[right]        {$v_{11}$} 
(4.5,6.2)   node[c] (v12) {} node[left]         {$v_{12}$}
(8.8,5)     node[c] (v13) {} node[left]         {$v_{13}$}
(9,7.5)     node[c] (v14) {} node[right]        {$v_{14}$}
(7,6.5)     node[c] (v15) {} node[above left]   {$v_{15}$}
(7,10)      node[c] (v16) {} node[above]        {$v_{16}$}
; 
    
\draw 
(v1)--(v2)--(v3)--(v1) 
(v3)--(v4)--(v2)--(v3)
(v4)--(v5)--(v2)--(v4) 
(v5)--(v6)--(v2)--(v5) 
(v1)--(v7)--(v3)--(v1) 
(v1)--(v8)--(v7)--(v1) 
(v1)--(v9)--(v8)--(v1)
(v9)--(v10)--(v8)    
(v7)--(v10)--(v3)
(v4)--(v10)--(v15)--(v4)
(v1) to[bend left=15] (v12) 
(v9)--(v12)--(v10)   
(v5)--(v11)--(v6)
(v12)--(v16)--(v15)--(v12)
(v4)--(v11)--(v5)
(v4)--(v13)--(v11)--(v14)
(v16)--(v14)--(v15)
(v15)--(v13)--(v14)
(v6) to[bend right=15] (v16) 
(v6) to[bend right=15] (v14) 
(v1) to[bend left=30] (v16) (v2) to[bend right] (v16)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Thank you so much gays.